# h2o.frame.unique() not extracting correct for enum

Tags: python, dataframe, h2o

I'm trying to extract unique values from a column in h2o data frame from python where filter is applied, but it keeps extracting all possible unique values. Is this a bug? I think this problem occurs only on enum type of columns... Example code provided.
H2O version 3.26.0.2

```py
df_example = h2o.H2OFrame({'time': ['M','M','M','D','D','M','M','D'],
              'amount': [1,4,5,0,0,1,3,0]})

df_example['amount'] = df_example['amount'].asfactor()

df_example[df_example['time']=='D', 'amount'].unique()
```

I expect to get one column data frame that has only 0 as value, but instead , I get one column data frame with values 0,1,2,3,4,5.

-edit-

What's even stranger, making new handle or deep copy of the dataframe does not solve the problem:

```py
df_example_new = df_example[df_example['time']=='D'] # I want only 'D'
df_example_new['time'].unique()  # still producing 'M' and 'D'

df_example_newest = h2o.deep_copy(df_example[df_example['time']=='D'], 'df_example_newest')
df_example_newest.unique() # again 'M' and 'D'
```

Comment: This is a bug in H2O. This happens because H2O creates a new temporary frame with correct values, but holds a reference to the original vec domain internally, as the domain is not recalculated - which leads to the output with original values shown above. I've created a PR to fix that issue: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/4848